# List variables with prefix where the prefix is stored in another variable

Tags: bash, string, variable

I'm trying to list all the variables with a certain prefix, but that prefix is dynamically determined.  For example:

```
prefix=apple_
apple_one=a1
apple_two=a2
```

If I simply do:

```
echo ${!apple_@}
```

I can get the variable names that start with apple_.  However, I would like to do this by using the variable prefix somehow.  Everything I've tried leads to a bad substitution.  For example I cannot:

```
echo ${!${prefix}@}
```

Comment: Depending on your exact problem, you might want to consider using arrays.

Comment: @Sparhawk I was thinking the same thing a little while after I submitted the question.  Am I really trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I only mention it because I've tried to do the same thing. I refactored to use arrays, and even though I had to modify what I was doing conceptually, it made more "sense" in the end. And seemed less hacky.

Comment: I had been trying to avoid associative arrays because I was burned a little while back due to portability issues. (I think they started support for that in Bash 4.)

Comment: I have this same requirement, with the additional stipulation that I be able to export the variables, so bash arrays are excluded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash doesn't parse nested variable expansions. You can do what you want with `eval`: build the shell snippet `${!apple_@}`, then use it in a command that you execute with `eval`.

```
prefix=apple_
eval 'vars=(${!'"$prefix"'@})'
```

Make sure that `prefix` contains only valid identifier characters, otherwise the snippet could result in anything.

`eval` is usually necessary to work with variables whose name is calculated dynamically, but in this specific case there's a completely different way to do the same thing: use the completion system. Bash's completion system works even from a script. The `compgen` builtin lists one completion per line, which is ambiguous when completions can contain newlines, but this isn't the case here — they don't even contain wildcard characters, so the output can be split with a simple unquoted expansion. This will safely output nothing if the prefix contains characters that aren't valid in identifiers.

```
vars=($(compgen -v "$prefix"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `env | grep '^prefix'`.

For example:

```sh
$ env | grep '^LESS'
LESSBINFMT=*u.
LESS=-MMqx4ij3
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
```

If you only want the values and not the variable names, use awk:

```sh
$ env | awk -F= '/^LESS/ {print $2}'
*u.
-MMqx4ij3
| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
```

(or print $1 for just the variable names)

---

## Update 2019-05-17

I was brought back to this answer by an upvote, and realised there's an obvious improvement:

`typeset -p` works better than `env`, it outputs all variables whether they're exported or not. For example:

```
typeset -p | awk '$3 ~ /^apple_/ { print $3 }'
```

To use a variable rather than a fixed string:

```
prefix=apple_
typeset -p | awk '$3 ~ "^"pfx { print $3 }' pfx="$prefix"
```

or just export $prefix so it's available in awk's ENVIRON array:

```
export prefix=apple_
typeset -p | awk '$3 ~ "^"ENVIRON["prefix"] { print $3 }'
```

**Note:** with a little work, this can be made to work with other shells such as ksh or zsh, but it is important to note that the output format for `typeset -p` is different in other shells, so the awk script will have to be modified to suit them.

Comment: Not if the variables aren't exported. And this can break if there are environment variables containing line breaks.

Comment: true.  nothing's perfect, and this is about as close as it's possible to get to what the OP wanted.  `set` could also be used if  you don't mind getting shell functions mixed in with your variables.

Comment: well, it wont put the function names out if you tell it to behave: `set -o posix; set`

Comment: @cas It's possible to get exactly what the OP wanted. It would be difficult if you wanted a POSIX solution, but `${!prefix}` is bash-specific in the first place (it isn't even a ksh feature).

Comment: `typeset -p` works better than `env`, outputs all variables whether they're exported or not.   e.g. `typeset -p | awk '$3 ~ /^BASH/ {print $3}'`, and avoids the potentially dangerous use of `eval`.   I should have remembered typeset when I first posted this answer.   to a variable rather than a fixed string:  `prefix="BASH"; typeset -p | awk '$3 ~ "^"prefix { print $3}' prefix="$prefix"`

Answer (score 0):

```
preset(){
    eval "printf %b $(#"
          set -- "${1##[0-9]*}" _\[:alnum:]
          [ -z   "${1##*[!$2]*}"  ]|| set |
          sed -ne"s/^\($1[$2]*\)=.*/"'"${\1+\1\\n}" \\/p')
"; }; #"

apple_one="a single apple"
apple_two="an apple and an
apple_three='is not actually set at all'
"

preset apple_
```

---

```
apple_one
apple_two
```